# Weird Android Memory Leak Presents On-Screen

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm getting some odd (and usually random) lines come into my long-running android apps.  Unfortunately I'm running Android Kitkat and I don't have some of the standard Android profiling and monitoring tools available.  Also unfortunately, upgrading the OS isn't an option because it is bundled with this rather nice hardware that has an integrated barcode reader and GPIO ports.

Have you run across weird screen stuff like this before?  What could be causing it?  Is there a way to force garbage collection or clean the screen?

[image]

Edits:  Also, we are running Teamviewer on the devices and these black marks show through on Teamviewer.  Could teamviewer be the culprit?

Comment: Just curious if a reboot fixes the issue or not?

Comment: A reboot does fix the issue.  I would love to programmatically reboot the device, but that requires some ninja os-signed capability on KitKat.  I'm all ears for ideas on a programatic reboot.

Comment: does the happen in other apps? It could be a vendor graphics driver issue, do you know the SoC name and software build version?

Comment: If the app isn't crashing, I would lean toward a graphics driver/graphics memory issue if the streaks are random and on multiple devices. Since it looks like a custom ROM, I would check if you can schedule a reboot outside of the Android framework (MDM perhaps?). Also hardware age can also be something to consider.

Comment: NQuire 300.  Android 4.4.2.  Kernel 3.4.39+  quel@Ubuntu14-lanfs #1.  Build #  NQuire300_V1.00.009.EN

Comment: My Thinkpad laptop had a similar issue Even Google Maps turned black both on chrome and edge. pink lines appearing randomly and nothing work. which was fixed after 3 years of update.  The last 7-8 months didn't face this issue again.   I also experience the same issue on Poco x3 which I got a replacement. It would randomly happen after I open the camera.
The possibility of your issue getting fixed is too low. If there is dirt inside the device. clean it. It is definitely not a memory leak. It is related to graphic device or its drivers. Reinstall the OS or drivers if possible.